# When is it appropriate to say "buenos días"?

Tags: saludos, cortesía, tiempo

## English

It looks like *"buenos días"* is most commonly translated as "good morning," although apparently it can mean "good day" as well (like a literal translation would suggest).

Is it appropriate to greet someone with *"buenos días"*, even if it's not morning? (eg: in English if say "good morning" to someone and it's 13:00 it might be construed as sarcastic).

## Español

Parece que *"buenos días"* se traduce mayoritariamente como "good morning", aunque aparentemente también puede significar "good day" (como sugeriría una traducción literal).

¿Es apropiado saludar a alguien con *"buenos días"*, aunque no sea por la mañana? (por ejemplo: en inglés decir "good morning" a una persona cuando son las 13:00 hrs se puede considerar sarcástico).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yeah it's the same in Spanish. You have to use "Buenos días" if you're in the morning,"Buenas tardes" for the afternoon/evening and "Buenas noches" at night.

It's difficult to say when you have to stop saying "Buenos días" and start saying "Buenas tardes". Literally, the point would be at noon, but at least in Spain people say "Buenos días" before having lunch and "Buenas tardes after that point" (Spanish people have lunch around 2 pm or so). The change between "Buenas tardes" and "Buenas noches" would be in the sunset but the change could also be done at dinner time.

But if you say "Buenos días" at 6pm it would be definitely strange.

Comment: In Bolivia, I heard this little joke: let's say that it's 2pm and you salute saying "Buenas tardes". She can say you: "Good morning. I still haven't had a lunch" ("Buenos días. Aún no he almorzado.")

Comment: Recently being in Costa Rica I find just the word "Buenas" being used to say hello, any time of day.

Comment: Is it appropriate in all contexts?

Answer (score 7):

- Buenos días -> until 12:00pm
- Buenas tardes -> from 12:01pm to last sun light
- Buenas noches -> after sunlight is gone
- Buen día differ if used like -> Que tenga un buen día = Have a nice day
  || Otherwise it can be interpreted as Good morning
- Variables such as Buenas are used in some countries | Buenas = Howdy (no time frame).

For those getting doubts or questions about this you should remember that some regions/countries may use different rules for which this answer may not apply.

**References and further reading:**

- http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Consultas/Consultas_ling%C3%BC%C3%ADsticas
- http://www.albaiges.com/cronologia/cuandoempiezatarde.htm
- http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=975209
- http://www.fundeu.es/consultas-B-buenos-dias-buenas-tardes-2146.html
- http://es.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070622014500AAaMy6Y

  As a side note, also something that should be taken into account when answering questions is that just because something is applicable in one country/region doesn't mean that is the rule and vise versa, the rule not always applies for all countries.

Comment: Where do you use this that sharp?

Comment: @JoulSauron everywhere! At leas if you are speaking in Spanish.

Comment: Read the other answer, in Spain we don't do it like that, that's why I'm asking where do you use your answer.

Comment: Perhaps you can say how do you say (time frame) in Spain

Comment: I told you to read the other answer, the one of Javi and already accepted.

Comment: @JoulSauron I read the answer, bu clearly says that it's difficult to say when one stop and the other begins. The true is that he refers to a specific situation in Spain which is not the rule for most Spanish speaking countries. To get more clarification in this matter you should check my improved answer

Comment: @It's not improved, it's just different, that's why I'm asking you to say where do you use this.

Comment: @JoulSauron Did you take a look to all that, did you check all these links?, Woow, you are fast men :) 95% of Latin America

Comment: I'm sorry, but when I wrote my previous comment I couldn't see your links, I apologize. :)
Just edit your answer to include that in 95% of Latin America you use it that way. The reason that I've been asking where are you from and where do you use this is because it's really up to the person or place when to say "buenos días" and so. Now with your answer the question is fully answered as it covers all Spanish speaking countries. :)