# ¿Es "buen día" una forma de decir "hola" sin importar el momento del día?

Tags: méxico, saludos, cortesía

En general, estamos de acuerdo en que [*Buenos días* se dice por la mañana](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/917/1674). Sin embargo, acabo de leer en un [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36969240#36969240):

> **A** — Buenos días.
>
> **B** — uy buenas tardes por aquí, @A.
>
> **C** — @B el saludo internacional es "Hola" o "**Buen día**".

Tanto A como C son de México y entiendo que allí se utiliza *buen día* como forma genérica. Sin embargo, ¿es este uso de *buen día* el generalizado? En España no lo reconozco y no encuentro ningún *Buen X* con algún *X* que sea genérico ([aunque empieza a oírse](http://www.elmundo.es/opinion/2017/09/06/59aef21c268e3eee488b4575.html)). Si saludas en general, debes decir *Hola* (o *Buenas* o similar).

Comment: Efectivamente, en España "*Buen día*" no se usa, yo intento popularizar "*Saludos*" como forma de saludar que no esté ligada a un horario.

Comment: Hay otras formas de saludar que no están asociadas a un horario, "qué onda" "queabido" "quihubo" (¿o es quiubo?) XD

Comment: @Rubén de hecho es "qué hubo", que creí común solo en Colombia. ¿Se usa también en México? Nota del autor: Rubén es el señor C.

Comment: @fedorqui: Mi comentario no pretende ser exhaustivo (: Por otro lado, soy jarrito de Tonalá, así que no me critiquen porque me *quebro* :P

Comment: Sin importar el momento, a mí me suena como "*buen día*" refiriéndose al *día* en general, no tanto categorizando como *día*, *tarde* o *noche*.

Comment: Ah, no debe faltar el "¡Ya llegué raza!"

Comment: Yo la verdad es que uso "buenos días" a cualquier hora del ídem... Bueno, salvo que sea noche cerrada, claro. Pero lo mío es por no pararme a pensar qué hora es... :-)

Comment: En Colombia "buen/os día/s" se usan en la mañana. Si alguien lo dice en la tarde le contestan "_¡[Q'hubo](http://www.qhubo.com/)!_ es que se acabó de levantar ¿o que?"

Comment: Yo no conocía "buen día" como solución del problem de las zonas temporales (? *time zones*), pero me parece genial, porque en México yo he visto precisamente lo que @dgaleano describió y lo que se pudo ver en el diálogo chat. // "Hola" no me parece tan buena solución internacional (universal) porque en ciertos medios da un poquito un efecto de español gringuizado, porque los extranjeros que llegan a México dicen *Hola* (mal pronunciado) en toda situación, y no se dan cuenta del choque cultural que causa.

Comment: @DGaleano ¿o sea que se usan _buen día_ y _buenos días_ indistintamente?

Comment: @fedorqui Si. Unas personas usan _buen día_ y otros preferimos _buenos días_ pero ambos son muy comunes y "algo" formales. En situaciones informales están: hola, ¿q'hubo, ¿q'tal?, ¿q'mas? ¿q'hay?.

Comment: @DGaleano - Cuando tengas tiempo, ¿haces una respuesta, por favor?  Tus comentarios llegan al grano.

Comment: Personalmente prefiero hola como saludo atemporal por excelencia, Puede ser que Buen día no se asocie específicamente a la mañana mientras que buenos días es obligatoriamente en la mañana, es decir que es posible usar buen día mas allá del medio día, pero es poco común al menos donde vivo. Aun que yo no lo usaría para saludo pero si lo uso comúnmente como despedida... Adios buen día.... buen día hasta luego....  etc. etc. etc. Saludos des México.

Comment: @Maurocrispin por lo que dices, parece que se usa _buen día_ como la forma corta de _que tengas un buen día_

Comment: Buen día se usa mas que todo en la mañana, En la tarde seria buenas tardes, Lo mismo que en la noche.

Comment: En francés sí se puede usar *Bonjour* en cualquier momento, siempre que sea la primera vez que te encuentras con una persona durante ese día. En español, la verdad, siempre había pensado que *Buen día* era una variante de *Buenos días* usada solo por la mañana, pero no conozco los usos de México u otros países.

Comment: @aparente001 No acabo de entender por qué consideras que *Hola* da efecto de español *gringuizado*. En español existe desde hace muchos siglos (al menos, recuerdo que en el Quijote ya aparece, aunque el uso es algo diferente al actual).

Comment: Pues yo uso un simple **Buenas** a cualquier hora del día.

Comment: Suelo usar "buenas" para evitar problemas.

Comment: It is complicated by the internet, in that the time that one writes something is not necessarily the time that it is read, and participants in a discussion are quite likely not in the same time zone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día y Buenos días son igual acá en México, generalmente cuando cuando saludas a alguien todos los días se saluda con "Buen día", es una forma de decir "que tengas buen día" y "buenos días" es para cuando no se saluda a la persona en cuestión en varios días.

Respondiendo a la pregunta: NO, no se usa "buen día" como sustituto de "Hola" en cualquier hora del día.

Comment: Do you have some URLs? I can't find an example, I've only found ""espero que tengas un buen día".

Answer (score 2):

- **"Buen día"**

En España, "Buen día" es perfectamente utilizable como saludo, al igual que "Hola", "Buenos dias" o "Buenas tardes". Quizás no es la opción más frecuente pero, muy dificilmente, no se interpretará como un saludo.

El uso del saludo es válido durante todo el día. Tanto mañana como tarde.

- **"Buenos días"**

En España, se utiliza únicamente por la mañana.

Según la RAE, la definición de mañana es:

> 1. f. Parte del día comprendida entre el amanecer y el mediodía, o la hora de comer o almorzar. Las mañanas de trabajo cunden mucho.

Una vez acabada la mañana, se pasa a usar "Buenas tardes" y después "Buenas Noches".

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, tremendows y bienvenido a [spanish.se]. Nótese que no estoy preguntando [_When is it appropriate to say “buenos días”?_](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/917/1674) sino si "buen día" (singular) se puede usar en algún lugar, especialmente México, para designar un "hola".

Answer (score 1):

*Buen día* siempre debe utilizarse cuando el sol está fuera y antes de las 12 PM. Si busca saber si se puede utilizar como otro modo de saludar, sí. El español presenta varios modos de saludar y *buen día* es uno de ellos.

Yo uso *buen día* de noche cuando quiero hacer reír a mi interlocutor. El uso como planteas no es muy usado en todos los países. Culturalmente lleva en si un deseo hacia el otro.

Hola y Saludos son maneras de saludar secas y casi egocéntricas. Menos personales, mientras buen día es desearle al otro un buen día. Saludos es también seco, impersonal.

Comment: @walen, gracias. Escribí muy rápido. Y no quise usar acentos por no user ALT.

Comment: La respuesta viene a decir _se usa buen día porque es una de las maneras de decirlo_. Entiendo que los que somos hablantes nativos podemos compartir nuestras experiencias, pero para que la respuesta tenga más empaque es bueno ofrecer referencias, ejemplos, etc. que lo sustenten.

Answer (score 0):

Esta frase muy en especial, varia en el sentido, me sirvo el hacerte llegar un enlace hacia un publicación en [Facebook](https://es-la.facebook.com/ortografiaygramatica1/photos/a.522203101143378.122104.155644707799221/813283415368677/?type=3), donde se explica el porque de la misma.

> En español existe un tipo de plural llamado "plural expresivo". Este es un plural que no denota cantidad, sino intensidad. Se usa mucho en fórmulas de respeto, como "gracias", "mis condolencias", "saludos", "felices fiestas", "felicidades", "besos y abrazos" y, claro, "buenos días (y buenas tardes/noches)".